# Is there a way to install keys into the opkg-keyring during the yocto build process and have them marks as ultimate rather than unknown by gpg

Tags: yocto, gnupg, bitbake, opkg

My problem I think is very simple. I would like to have *opkg* verify signatures before installing packages from my custom *opkg* repository. The issue I am having is that the keys I added to the *opkg-keyrings yocto* recipe are all marked as unknown on the target by *gpg*. They are all installed though. So when i attempt to install a package form my custom repository, It fails because there are no trusted keys. I do not believe that this is a *yocto* bug, but I am running *rocko*.

Thank you.

I have gone through the relevant recipes and just don't see anything to change the behavior.

when i attempt to run opkg update i receive the following error.

**Collected errors:**

> opkg_verify_gpg_signature: No sufficently trusted public keys found.

```
gpg -k result on target(verify fails)
uid           [ unknown]

gpg -k result on pc where verify succeeds. 
uid   
        [ultimate]
```

Comment: Does [this manual section](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#processing-package-feeds) helps?

Comment: thank you Nayfe but no. I have already done that. My keys are on the target an opkg is aware of them. It just has set them all to unknown rather than a trusted state.

Comment: opkg-key adv --list-keys --fingerprint --with-colons |\
sed -E -n -e 's/^fpr:::::::::([0-9A-F]+):$/\1:6/p' |\
opkg-key adv --import-ownertrust  \n I wanted to add this for anyone who finds the question. I ended up adding a service at start up that runs a script that enables the key

Comment: You can add it as an answer to your question, and mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opkg-key populate
opkg-key adv --list-keys --fingerprint --with-colons |\ 
sed -E -n -e 's/^fpr:::::::::([0-9A-F]+):$/\1:6/p' |\ 
opkg-key adv --import-ownertrust

I wanted to add this for anyone who finds the question. I ended up adding a service at start up that runs a script that enables the keys. I have included the key portions of the script above.